# Eclipse XML editor in Flash Builder

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

Eclipse (at least the JDT package) comes with a pretty decent XML editor. Flash Builder (based on Eclipse), however, does not. Is there a way to install this XML editor into Flash Builder as a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to install it from the Eclipse release train site that is compatible with your version of Flash Builder (e.g. http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/ for Eclipse 3.5), it's part of the Web Tools (choose Help > Install New Software and add the URL above, then select Web Tools).